# Custom tag or code to determine if a specific date is a holiday

Tags: coldfusion, custom-tags

I need to figure out if a particular date falls on a holiday, such as Memorial Day, Labor Day, Thanksgiving, Easter, etc. However, these holidays float based on week of month or day of week. I'm sure there is code out there to do this, so I'd hate to reinvent the wheel.

Specifically, I will have a date that something occurs and want to add information about that date, or do extra things (such as add extra pay), if the event happens on a holiday. Something like this, but for every federal holiday:

```
if ( month( date ) == 9 && day( date ) < 8 && DayOfWeek( date ) == 2 ) {
    holiday = 'labor day';
}
```

On a side note, does anyone know a working URL for the CF custom tag library, or did they kill that?

Comment: You might want to tap into a Java library. See `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388673/holidays-is-there-a-java-implementation`

Comment: Are you referring to [cflib.org](http://cflib.org/)? It includes a function that gives German holidays which you may be able to adopt for the US - http://cflib.org/udf/getBankHolidays

Comment: We all have our own toys to play with and one of mine is a database with a calendar table where one of the fields is holiday.  I use it.  Where it really comes in handy is when a holiday falls on a weekend and either the Monday or Friday gain holiday status.

Answer (score 4):

You can access & cache the Google Calendar US Holiday feed. You'll need to register for a free API key. "FullCalendar" has instructions on establishing establishing a Calendar account for use w/JS, but you can use CF to consume the JSON once it's configured.

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/

View the source and server JSON response on this page using browser developer F12 tools:

http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.5.0/demos/gcal.html

The URL you will use will look something like this (but with your own API key):

https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/usa__en@holiday.calendar.google.com/events?key=AIzaSyDcnW6WejpTOCffshGDDb4neIrXVUA1EAE

The JSON response you get back will have a "items" array containing holiday infomation and the dates in ISO8601 format.

```
"items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"2778476758000000\"",
   "id": "20140101_60o30dr46oo30c1g60o30dr4ck",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/event?eid=MjAxNDAxMDFfNjBvMzBkcjQ2b28zMGMxZzYwbzMwZHI0Y2sgdXNhX19lbkBo",
   "created": "2014-01-09T03:32:59.000Z",
   "updated": "2014-01-09T03:32:59.000Z",
   "summary": "New Year's Day",
   "creator": {
    "email": "usa__en@holiday.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "Holidays in United States",
    "self": true
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "usa__en@holiday.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "Holidays in United States",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "date": "2014-01-01"
   },
   "end": {
    "date": "2014-01-02"
   },
   "transparency": "transparent",
   "visibility": "public",
   "iCalUID": "20140101_60o30dr46oo30c1g60o30dr4ck@google.com",
   "sequence": 0
  }
]
```

I recommend saving the API response data (so you can reuse it locally without having to rely on the remote API) and generate a struct using ISO8601 dates as the keys (yyyy-MM-DD) and have the value be an array of holiday names.  You may want to extend this to denote whether it's a Federal "paid" holiday or not as I don't believe the Google Calendar API (or any holiday date library) will identify that for you.

```
Holidays = {
   "2015-12-31" = ["New Year's Eve"],
   "2016-01-01" = ["New Year's Day"]
}
```

and then use something like this as your logic:

```
holidayNames = '';
if (StructKeyExists(Holidays, DateFormat(theDate, "yyyy-MM-DD"))){
    holidayNames = ArrayToList(Holidays[DateFormat(theDate, "yyyy-MM-DD")]);
}
```

**UPDATE** While googling for a ColdFusion-based library, I realized I wrote a GetGoogleHolidays UDF a year prior. (The UDF fetchs US holiday JSON data using the Google Calendar API, generates a struct with YYYYMMDD keys that contains an array of holiday names and caches it for 24 hours.)

http://gamesover2600.tumblr.com/post/104768724954/fetch-holiday-dates-from-google-calendar-api-using

Comment: *saving the API response data* Might also consider storing the holidays in a more normalized form, ie creating some sort of calendar table, as [Dan mention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34359392/coldfusion-custom-tag-or-code-to-tell-me-if-a-date-is-a-holiday#comment56461600_34359392). That provides a lot of flexibility for other queries, reports, etcetera.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the UDF I wrote a year ago. I usually only use the calendar data when displaying it on a webpage, so using a cached struct worked well for my needs. The data could be databased if you needed to write queries based on it, but it would also mean that you'd need to consume a wider date range in the feed to ensure future date queries are covered.

Comment: Yep. Since most of the apps I work on include a lot of reporting and date related queries, my preference is calendar tables.  However, like you said, it all depends on the needs of the app.