# Weekends for Middle East Countries

Tags: java, if-statement, apex, countries

I need to check the conditions based on the weekend of the given countries. Most of the countries weekends are Saturday and Sunday. I know that the Middle East Countries like Turkey, Israel, Iran, Saudi Arabia weekend format is different. I need to know the weekends of the Middle East Countries so that I can check the conditions as per country. I checked in Wikipedia but couldn't find the exact result.

What I have found,

```
 **Countries**                    **Working Days**

Turkey
Israel        --------      Sunday–Thursday
Iran          --------      Saturday–Thursday
Saudi Arabia  --------      Sunday–Thursday
United Arab Emirates -      Sunday–Thursday
Iraq          --------      Sunday–Thursday
Yemen         --------      Sunday–Thursday
Lebanon       --------      Monday–Friday      
Qatar         --------      Sunday–Thursday
Jordan        --------      Sunday–Thursday
Kuwait        --------      Sunday–Thursday
Oman          --------      Sunday–Thursday
Bahrain       --------      
Tunisia
Cyprus
```

I don't know whether these are correct formats or not. Please help me to know about working days/weekends of the above mentioned countries

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388673/holidays-is-there-a-java-implementation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for a list of weekends in various countries is not about programming.

Comment: If you spend about three seconds googling, you'll find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend

Comment: I found the above informations from the same wikipedia site. But still there are some doubts about Turkey, Bahrain, Tunisia, Cyprus