# Java weekend calculator API / Library

Tags: java, date, calendar, timestamp, dayofweek

Lets say I have 2 dates in milliseconds or java.sql.Timestamp:

```
1342162320 <->  Fri Jul 13 2012 09:52:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)
1343162320 <-> Tue Jul 24 2012 23:38:40 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)
```

Lets say I provide these 2 dates, and I need:

**Return int, if the time between JUL 13 09:52 - JUL 24 23:58 falls on weekends or big holidays, and if so, how many days.**

I thought about just going through all dates, and checking if it is saturday or sunday, but maybe some more clever APIs?

I also looked into Joda library, but it does not specifically have these methods, just has some simplified JDK ones. Joda does not have holiday recognition.

Comment: Holidays? You mean like for every country in the world with all variations? What about different religions in same country, their religious holidays dont match.

Comment: @Max Hmm, I mean like RED holidays in calenders, only the big ones. Kind of global ones.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1044921/a-good-business-calendar-library-in-java , that might be the think you are looking for.

Comment: There are no "global" holidays. All of them are country/religion specific. Or are you good with providing list of "red" dates manually, as per @ortang's solution?

Comment: Those numbers look like a count from 1970 in *whole* seconds not *milliseconds*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use defined holiday calendars from http://www.calendarlabs.com/ical-calendar-holidays.php, they are available for a number of countries. It's format is called iCal, used by MS Outlook. It shouldn't be to hard to write a parser for that format. Then you have the 'red' dates and don't have to define and update, just download a new definition for every year.

It might also be possible to get the holidays from Google Calendars or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is very easy，Just follow the below codes:

```
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setTime(date);
    //cal.setTimeInMillis(milliseconds); use this one instead if you have milliseconds. 
    int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if(Calendar.SUNDAY == dayOfWeek || Calendar.SATURDAY == dayOfWeek){
        System.out.println("it is saturday or sunday")
   }
```

This can recognize that the day is Saturday or Sunday, but if you want to determine whether it is public holiday? eg: national holiday, I would say that could be impossible via JDK, since this is very in accordance on different regions or countries, it is not permanent.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Boolean isWeekend = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ).contains ( Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1342162320L ).atZone( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Helsinki" ) ).getDayOfWeek() )
```

## Details

The other Answers are correct but use outmoded legacy classes. Use java.time classes instead.

The weekend part of the Question is easy with built-in Java libraries. You can define the set of days that is a weekend, such as Saturday & Sunday in the United States.

Covering holidays requires some kind of external library, web service, or database. The definition of holidays varies over time and by jurisdiction and by tradition. I will ignore that part of the Question; see the [Answer by Kennet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11466494/642706) as one possible solution.

## `DayOfWeek`

The `DayOfWeek` enum identifies each of the seven days of the week. You can interrogate a `ZonedDateTime` for its `DayOfWeek`.

First parse you input number. Appears to be a count of whole seconds since the epoch of first moment of 1970 in UTC. Note the `L` on the end to make this a `long` integer.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( 1342162320L );
```

Apply a time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Helsinki" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId );
```

Test for weekend by asking if the day of week is either Saturday or Sunday.

```
DayOfWeek dow = zdt.getDayOfWeek();
Boolean isWeekend = ( dow.equals( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY ) || dow.equals( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) );
```

## `EnumSet`

You could also use an [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html), for fast execution and low memory usage.

```
Set<DayOfWeek> weekend = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY );
```

Declare this as a `static final` constant if its definition does not change during execution of your app.

```
static final Set<DayOfWeek> WEEKEND = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY );
```

When you get a `DayOfWeek` object, see if it is contained in the EnumSet which is an implementation of [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface.

```
Boolean isWeekend = WEEKEND.contains( dow.getDayOfWeek() );
```

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.