# What is the easiest way to check if a date is a business day (inclusive and exclusive of US holidays) in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

## something like

is_Business_day(date) returns true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`date.weekday()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) function to get the weekday that a date is on. Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6, so a business day would be `mydate.weekday() < 5`

Comment: this doesn't consider holidays right?  Is there a way to check for valid business day?

Comment: @HC That's very nation-specific; countries don't celebrate the same holidays. I doubt Python includes a list of every country's holidays.

Comment: @H C: [_Best free library or database to determine if a date is a US or international holiday?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736852/best-free-library-or-database-to-determine-if-a-date-is-a-us-or-international-ho) might help with the holiday determination. It looks like there's only 11 in the US, so you could easily create a table of them to check against.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
from bdateutil import isbday

isbday(date, holidays = holidays.US())
```